# Looking for /etc/network/interfaces is missing?

Tags: networking, network-bridge

So I have a newly installed ubuntu machine. I was going to enter some network setup, but this file is missing: `/etc/network/interfaces`. I also checked with `root`. There is a local loopback on the machine. Shouldn't it be  ? is it just a matter of creating it from scratch and it will be picked up automaticly on reboot ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't told us your Ubuntu version, but I assume you have **Ubuntu 18.04 or above** based on your missing file.

Ubuntu 18.04 and above use  [netplan](https://netplan.io/) to configure your network, and `/etc/network/interfaces` does not exist anymore. The netplan configuration file should be at `/etc/netplan/`.

You may still switch back to using the old method (not recommended) by installing the relevant packages:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ifupdown net-tools
```

If you would like to change your NICs names to the old representation, you'll need to change a grub parameters at `/etc/default/grub`:
Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"`.
Perform `$ sudo update-grub` afterwords and reboot.

Any other changes regarding IP addresses, dns and other configuration methods should be the same as you know from past expirience.